# Need assistance with converting mysqli_fetch_array references to corresponding OCI references

Tags: php, mysql, oracle, mysqli, oracle-call-interface

On a MySQL database, I'm using the following PHP code to successfully retrieve rows and place the contents of two columns into a table:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
  echo '<tr>
        <td>'.$row['sc_service'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['sc_color'].'</td>
        </tr>';
}
```

Now, I'm trying to take this code and use it against an Oracle database. I've tried swapping in what appears to be the OCI counterpart...

```
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid1, OCI_BOTH))!= false)
{
  echo '<tr>
          <td>'.$row['sc_service'].'</td>
          <td>'.$row['sc_color'].'</td>
        </tr>';
}
```

...but the column variables (`sc_service` and `sc_color`) are not being defined.

Question: Is there a different approach required to define the column variable? I'd like to use the variables in other areas of the PHP code, and not just to populate a table.

I'm able to execute the following PHP script successfully using OCI functions (a properly populated table is returned), so I know I'm connecting to the database successfully:

```
<?php include 'database.php'; ?>  // my Oracle database oci_connect call

<?php

$stid = oci_parse($connect, 'SELECT * FROM service_color');
if (!$stid) {
  $e = oci_error($connect);
  trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}

$r = oci_execute($stid);
if (!$r) {
  $e = oci_error($stid);
  trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}

print "<table border='1'>\n";
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
  print "<tr>\n";
  foreach ($row as $item) {
    print "    <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "</td>\n";
  }
  print "</tr>\n";
}
print "</table>\n";

oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($connect);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Field names in Oracle are typically always uppercase, and array keys in PHP are case-sensitive:

```
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($stid1, OCI_BOTH))!= false)
{
  echo '<tr>
        <td>'.$row['SC_SERVICE'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['SC_COLOR'].'</td>
        </tr>';
}
```

Comment: I made the change from lower-case to upper-case, and that corrected my issue. Thanks so much!